# How can I tell my method to ignore an exception and continue running?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

how can I prevent an error in one part of my controller method from causing the whole method from returning a 500 error?

I have this controller method that should delete a row in my database:

```
    // DELETE: api/FaunaLists/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<FaunaList>> DeleteFaunaList(string id)
    {
        // delete any associated references in FaunaList_EcosystemList table
        // if that table doesn't have any references, this whole method throws a 500 error :(
        if (faunaList.EcosystemId != null)
        {
            faunaEcosystemRef = _context.FaunaList_EcosystemList.Where(x => x.EcosystemId == faunaList.EcosystemId).ToList();
            _context.FaunaList_EcosystemList.RemoveRange(faunaEcosystemRef);
        }
        
        try
        {
            _context.FaunaList.Remove(faunaList);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Message = _loggingMessage.GetLogException(this.GetType().Name.ToString(), ControllerActions.Exception, "FaunaList DELETE", id.ToString(), e.InnerException.ToString());
            _logger.LogCritical(Message);
            return BadRequest("Error when saving database changes. See error details.");
        }
        
        return faunaList;
        
    }
```

In the method, you can see I check for an Id called `faunaList.EcosystemId`.

If that exists, then I try to delete it.

However, if the `EcosystemId` doesn't exist in the FaunaList_EcosystemList table, it throws this error in the browser:

DELETE https://sci-measure.xyz.gov/api/FaunaLists/TTE37B02-7624-4ED5-B62D-B7832C0D7E60 net::ERR_FAILED 500

How can I ignore that error and just let the rest of the method continue to execute?

Thanks!

Comment: `if (faunaEcosystemRef.Count > 0)  { ... remove range }`? But why don't you move the first part of the code into the try-block or into a new try-catch?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks! Will moving it into a `try-block` prevent it from throwing a 500 error to the browser?  thanks! again!

Comment: Apparently you are getting an exception in your code. What *is* it exactly, why does it occur? Can you *prevent* it instead of ignoring it?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I know why it's happening and it's not a big deal.  At this point, I want to just log it and have the app continue and move on so it doesn't interrupt the user experience.  Is that possible?  Thanks!

Comment: What is `faunaList`, or rather where did it get a value? Are you sure it isn't null?

Comment: If you just want to ignore any exception, then wrap that `try` around the whole code. And maybe not return a BadRequest?

Comment: You need to share the actual exception being thrown by the code. Not the 500 error you receive in the browser.  I suspect the actual problem is a null reference exception being cause by this line `faunaEcosystemRef = _context.FaunaList_EcosystemList.Where(x => x.EcosystemId == faunaList.EcosystemId).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write try-catch block like so:

```
try{
 //your code here
}
catch(Exception){
 //your code here
}
```

It will catch every exception.

If you only want to catch one certain exception, you can specify that in the catch like so:

```
try{
  // your code here
}
catch(SpecificException){
  // your code here
}
```

This code will catch the specific exception and ignore others.

Or you can create a try-catch block for the if statement and write the `continue` keyword and it will continue with the code.

Comment: In my instance, I don't want it to throw a 500 error.  I want it to kind of ignore the error and move on because any error in that block of code can be logged and examined if needed.  I don't want the user experience ruined. Basically I just want the code to be like, well that didn't work, moving on... :)

Comment: Create a new catch block for the if statement and get some exception that you know won't return, it will then go on with the code.

Comment: Or you can catch the exception you want to ignore and write the continue keyword in the catch block

Comment: `continue` will only work in loops, you don't need it here. Just catch the exception, maybe log it and don't throw it again